# Should this be volatile or is the result unpredictable?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

Is a `volatile` required in the `kill` variable that controls the execution of the thread?

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{  

  private boolean kill = false;  

  public void killThread(){  
      kill = true;  
  }  

  @Override  
  public void run(){  
     while(!kill){  
                 //do stuff  
     }  
  }  

}
```

For example if in some other part of the code (another thread) I do `theThreadRef.killThread();` should I expect the thread to stop or is the result **unpredictable** due to not having declared `kill` as `volatile`? I am not sure on this since I update the `kill` via the `killThread` method.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `kill` is a variable shared between threads and must be `volatile`. However, consider using Java's native interruption mechanism, involving `Thread.interrupt()` and `Thread.interrupted()`, to achieve what you need. Then you won't need to keep your own variable.

Comment: Thank you.My main concern is whether this piece of code has a predictable behavior or not. So we can not be sure whether the thread will end, right?

Comment: Your piece of code definitely has unpredictable behavior. Even more than that, it would be almost typical behavior that your thread never observes changes to `kill` due to optimization technique known as "hoisting". The compiler is allowed to assume that `kill` will never be changed from other threads and, depending on the rest of your code, may even displace the read of `kill` to outside the loop and turn the loop into a `while (true)`. Even without hoisting, the value of `kill` will be written to thread-local storage and never updated.

Comment: You don't have to declare variables volatile just because they are shared between requests. You declare them volatile to ensure a happens-before relationship between the threads. That relationship doesn't really make sense to establish in the given example (there is no observable difference between establishing it and not establishing it).

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz You need to ensure a `happens-before` between a write to that var and any subsequent read of it by the shown code. That's exactly what `volatile` is for.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:This is existing code.What should I look to suspect the optimization you mention? More or less the structure of the code of the thread is as posted

Comment: Correct, but what does the happens-before relationship give me here? MyThread does not call back to anywhere...

Comment: @Jim Just don't worry about the details of possible optimizations by the JIT compiler. If you put `volatile` on the `kill` var, it will be fine.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz It gives you termination of the thread's main loop.

Comment: Ok, I don't think my comments here are helping anyone, so I will stop here. It will definitely work if the variable is declared `volatile`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:The fact that the variable is primitive `boolean` doesn't it mean that the update is atomic?

Comment: The update is indeed atomic, but without `volatile` it is not guaranteed to ever be observed by the reading thread.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, it's often forgotten that `interrupt()` may require privileges to be invoked, virtually I do not use it to gracefully terminate threads (at least not directly and solely) - also under C1 (-client) `Thread.interriupted()` may not be optimized properly.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz, it has to be volatile to ensure the compiler (JVM) does not optimize  away the check, effectively turning into an endless loop. Happens-before stuff is not that important (baring stopping before starting)

Comment: @bestsss Imposing `happens-before` is not at all about proper event ordering in this case, but is all about **visibility** of the write action. Though we may go on about how little guarantees you get from the JLS even with the `happens-before` in place, in practice any means of ensuring a proper `happen-before` ordering (be it `volatile` or anything else) **does** ensure a timely publish of that write to the reading thread.

Comment: I am sure you well know that visibility on any hardware platform that java presently runs is ensured by the hardware itself (as long as the compiler doesn't optimize away the read, AFAIK there are no write optimizations as of now), hence `AtomicXXX.lazySet` is a clear winner in many concurrent cases, i.e. if the boolean is changed to `AtomicBoolean` and `lazySet(true)` it'd work just as fine even on the weirdest hardware memory models.

Comment: @bestss `AtomicBoolean` does not even possess `lazySet`, but if we used an `AtomicInteger` instead, it would still be a very dangerous practice to use it as it depends on `happens-before` being imposed by some action.

Comment: *AtomicBoolean does not even possess lazySet*, are you looking at 1.5, lazySet is available since 1.6: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#lazySet%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you do not declare `kill` as `volatile`, other threads may keep reading the old value after a different thread made a new assignment. When or if the value gets updated is undefined, so in that sense the behavior is unpredictable (in practice, the new assignment eventually becomes visible).

However, because assignment of a primitive boolean value is atomic, the value will be always a "proper/valid" value (i.e. either `true` or `false` and never an invalid value). So in that sense, the behavior is not completely unpredictable (your code won't crash etc.). Note that this is not the case for `long` types or for non-primitive objects. Primitive int types also have the same property as primitive boolean, and this is famously used to optimize hash code calculation in the Standard Library's String class implementation.